# How to generate AUTOMATIC Number in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, auto-increment, teradata

I want to generate AUTOMATIC Number to use TD SQL, for example as follows,

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE TEST_TABLE
(
  AUTO_NUMBER INT,
  NAME VARCHAR(10)
)
PRIMARY INDEX (AUTO_NUMBER);

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE
VALUES('TOM');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE
VALUES('JIM');
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE
VALUES('JAN');

SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

The result above will be ,

```
1 TOM
2 JIM
3 JAN
```

Comment: In this way you can add an autoincrement column: http://forums.teradata.com/forum/enterprise/auto-increment-column

Comment: TERADATA SQL ASSISTENT

Comment: Hi Joe,thanks,teradata forums it's a nice place for me

Comment: Do you actually need a sequence without gaps? 1,2,3? IDENTITY doesn not guarantee sequencial numbers, in fact it's not a single sequence but multiple sequences for each AMP/PE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a column with the below syntax:

```
SEQ_NUM decimal(10,0) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
           (START WITH 1 
            INCREMENT BY 1 
            MINVALUE 1 
            MAXVALUE 2147483647 
            NO CYCLE)
```

Comment: will this work on a preexisting table with already populated rows?

Answer (score -1):

Usually there is a column in the table which is unique.

You can use below technique to add a column in your result set if you dont want to add extra column to your table.

select RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY ),T.* SEQ from TABLE T;

It will give you output like:

1 a xx yy
2 b xx yy
3 c xx yy